# Python - beauitful soup output to csv only showing 1 record

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

Problem: when i print data to see its structure, its good. But when i output to csv im getting only the last record where each character separated line by line instead of all records.

for example: 
Python code output:

```
johnsmith123jghoststreet902231131
laracroft23jghoststreet902231131
janecone23jghoststreet902231131
```

when i output to csv it shows

```
j

a

n

e

c

o
```

etc...just the last records

This is the code

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import csv
#ignore SSL errors
ctx=ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.omielife.com/pages/retailers"
,context=ctx).read().decode('utf-8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

links= soup.find_all('p')
print(links)
#a_data = soup.find_all(class_='p') #itemprop="streetaddress"> address </span>
for item in links:
    print(item.text, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=True)
    a=item.text


with open('test2.csv','w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerows(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, both a list of a string and a single string are iterable.  In your code, `a` is a single string.  But you pass it to `writerows()` which expects multiple strings.

You should be building up a list in `a` of multiple strings--then `writerows()` will do what you expect.

Comment: could you point to how i could do that or provide me with example pls?

Comment: @tabarneck: Make a list called `a`.  Append all your `item.text`s to it.

Comment: for item in links:
    print(item.text, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=True)
    a=item.text
page_List=[]
for page_data in a:
        page_List.append(page_data)
        print(page_List.text, sep=' ', end='\n', flush=True)

Comment: its not liking the a.item.text in the list. I get an error "list has no text"